# Magento cancelled orders log

Tags: magento

We have multiple users managing customer orders online.  I need a way to track who cancelled a particular order using the admin.  Is there any way to do that?

We are using Magento Enterprise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento EE<sup>*</sup> has a built-in feature called `Admin Actions Logs` for such kind of things.

Call `Admin Actions Logs -> Report`, then just type `adminhtml_sales_order_cancel` into the "Full Action Name" filter box and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. There you go^^

---

<sup>* At least EE 1.11 (and higher). I don't know in which version of EE it was first implemented, though.</sup>